# How to use Replace using some factor from exponent in the replacement rule

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, factorization

Is it possible to directly factor out some exponent to some specific form and replace by some rule?
For example I have

```
exp1=x^4
```

I want to use replacement

```
/. x^2 ->z
```

where I do NOT want to change the replacement rule like

```
% /. x^a_->z^(a/2)
```

I wanted to know whether any simple procedure is there for direct replacement i.e.

```
x^4 /. {x^2->z} = z^2
```

Comment: You could try `x-> Sqrt[z]`.

Comment: This is same as using x^a_->z^(a/2). As I said I do not want to change the replacement rule. The question is stupid, also Mathematica may not work like this. I wanted to know whether there is 'Something' for
Something[x^4] /. {x^2->z} = z^2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps for your actual use case, but you can try using [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify):

```
Simplify[x^4, x^2==z]
```

> z^2

Comment: Sorry this is not what I meant. This question has obviously many answer as way out. I was thinking of putting some module which factors out x^4 to x^2 * x^2 and do the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could give more examples; but it sounds like what you're trying to do is replace a composite variable (x^2), rather than just x.  You can do this by holding the expression containing the composite variable in an unevaluated state, as follows:

```
Unevaluated[x^2] /. x^2 -> z
```

> z

For more complicated composite variables, you might need to do something like this:

```
Unevaluated[x^2] /. HoldPattern@x^2 -> z
```

That's not needed for the above example, but it is for this:

```
Unevaluated[
2 Exp[-\[Beta] (Subscript[\[Epsilon], 
   R] - \[Mu])] Exp[-\[Beta] \[Epsilon]]] /. 
   HoldPattern@Exp[-\[Beta] (Subscript[\[Epsilon], R] - \[Mu])] :> x
```

The one limitation you'll encounter is that the composite variable to be substituted needs to appear in the exact form you use in the replacement statement.  Thus this will return z^2:

```
Unevaluated[x^2*x^2] /. x^2 -> z
```

...but this will return x^4:

```
Unevaluated[x^4] /. x^2 -> z
```